# If it's possible, what conditions need to be met to perform a CSV import for a single-location Bin Transfer in NetSuite?

Tags: csv, import, mapping, netsuite, csv-import

I need to be able to create new Bin Transfer records (document number prefixes with BT) using a newly created Saved CSV Import instance. After uploading my first few attempts of the CSV file into NetSuite, I keep receiving an error column within my result.csv saying "You cannot create an inventory detail for this item."

What condition needs to be met for me to avoid this issue?

Here is my CSV file contents:

`itemid,from bin,tobin,Quantity,Externalid
TESTSKU,A1,A2,20,j20190624`

I have consulted NetSuite Answers by lodging them a new case and was asked if the items were lot numbers or serialized numbers

I then referred to 'NetSuite Help Center' about "Lot Numbered Items" as well as "Serial Numbered Items", I also consulted my management department to be told that our current system uses neither of these two choices.

When I created `TESTSKU` in our SANDBOX environment, the ITEM TYPE is set to "Inventory Item" as advised. Therefore I responded to them that it is not a "Lot Numbered" nor a "Serialized item" and received no more emails back from them (in attempt to force another inactivity trigger to close the support case as it has been done me to prior support cases).

I have also performed several failed CSV imports where:

- I changed the values of the Item column of the CSV file.
- I changed the values of the Bin column of the CSV file.
- I changed the External ID column to a unique value of the CSV file.
- I mapped the quantity column into two places to stop an unrelated error.
- The IMPORT TYPE of the Saved CSV import is set to Transactions and RECORD TYPE has been set to Inventory Adjustment. (I did manage to successfully perform the import but to the clearly wrongly selected record type. It produced an IA prefixed record instead of the desired BT prefixed record)
- The IMPORT TYPE of the Saved CSV import is set to Transactions and RECORD TYPE has been set to Inventory Transfer to no success.
- The IMPORT TYPE of the Saved CSV import is set to Transactions and RECORD TYPE has been set to Transfer Order to no success.

I recall that I was able to perform a Saved CSV Import for a different occasion helping someone else that involved Inventory Transfer and this produced an IT prefixed record.

At this point, this made me wonder: what Record Type do I select for a RECORD TYPE to produce a BT prefixed record?

Here is my initial mapping configuration:

- Import Type: Transactions
- Record Type: Item Transfer (incorrect?)

Here is gist of my mapping configuration:

- (CSV column = NetSuite field)
- `To Bin = Inventory Transfer Items - Inventory Detail: To Bins`
- `From Bin = Inventory Transfer Items - Inventory Detail: Bin`
- `Quantity = Inventory Transfer Items - Inventory Detail: Quantity`
- `Quantity = Inventory Transfer Items: Qty to Transfer`
- `ItemID = Inventory Transfer Items: Item`

Irrelevant fields has been omitted here intentionally such as date and subsidiary fields.

The NetSuite mapping of `Inventory Transfer: From Location` has been set to the intended static single location. I have joined the above using the UI for those that did not automatically link through the Import Assistant.

The expected result of the CSV Import would be "All records imported successfully."
The actual result of the CSV Import says 
"You cannot create an inventory detail for this item." exactly on the error column of a downloaded results.csv file

I admit that I am missing and struggling to obtain many important details and conditions as well as proper mappings and circumstances for our system to be able to perform a Bin Transfer using a Saved CSV Import.

Any help or support towards solving this would much well be appreciated and a huge benefit to those in my position too.

**EDIT:** *I am willing to accept answers where the CSV Import Assistant will produce an "Item Transfer" or different type Transaction record since as of 27th June 2019 because there may not be an option in our account to produce "Bin Transfer" type Transaction records through CSV Import Assistant at all.*

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can create Bin Transfer records via CSV import.  That option is not available in my account.  An Inventory Transfer is used specifically to move from one location to another and you cannot enter the same location in the from/to fields. Also, based on the error message, ensure that "Use Bins" is checked on the item in question.  If no, the inventory detail field will not be available.

Comment: according to this https://i.ibb.co/44fjGNB/2019-06-25-11-29-02-Inventory-Item.png I thought that "Use Bins" is checked for my particular item. I guess this is an actual missing feature in this point in time or a feature not enabled in our package of NetSuite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea is to produce an Inventory Adjustment, where I would decrement the SOURCE bin and then increment the DESTINATION bin afterwards. I would have to make the location and designated account set as a STATIC value in the CSV Import Assistant mappings section.

It is a simpler sounding idea, however it does produce an Inventory Adjustment transaction record instead.

Answer (score 0):

One of my ideas is to produce a two-step Item Transfer, where I would create a sublocation within our existing location. I also created a "Temporary Bin" within my `Temporary Location`.

Simply put on a Location level:

- Step #1: Location A → Temporary Location
- Step #2: Temporary Location → Location A

(At a bin level:)

- Step #1: SOURCE bin → Temporary Bin
- Step #2: Temporary Bin → DESTINATION bin

This may require two sets of external IDs and will produce two sets of Item Transfer transaction records, but it gets the job done of moving inventory items from one bin to another while keeping it in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Are all items with "use bins" enabled? That is what this error from the import means

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).